# How to properly implement a persistent CookieStore without reflection?

Tags: java, cookies

By default the JRE provides an in memory implementation of the [CookieStore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/CookieStore.html) enabling the [CookieManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html) to save [HttpCookies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html) during runtime. 
Eventually it is desired to keep cookies and sessions even after the JVM shut down.

The cookie manager documentation states:

> CookieStore is the place where any accepted HTTP cookie is stored in.
>   If not specified when created, a CookieManager instance will use an
>   internal in-memory implementation. **Or user can implements one and tell
>   CookieManager to use it**.

Serializing of an HTTPCookie without reflection is not possible since the `maxAge` field is a duration defining the cookies lifetime in seconds since creation. This value is only meaningful in combination with the private `whenCreated`field of the object which isn't accessible via any getter method.
Every solution I have found so far disregards this fact and is broken.

We could implement our own `CookieHandler` and replace the default `HttpCookie` by our own `SerializedHttpCookie` instance instead, but the `HttpCookie` class itself is defined as final, therefore we can't extend it and comply with the interface contract.

The only "working" solution so far is to extends the CookieHandler and create a map to save the creation time separately. But this is just hackish and a nightmare to keep all references in synch.

How can a "user" implement a persistent cookie store without reflection?

**Tldr**: Jdk9+ isn't fond of reflection. HttpCookies can't be serialized without it. How do you persistently save cookies?